# Load dictionary from .npy file in mmap mode

Tags: python, numpy, file

So, I have a number of large .npy files (~600MB each) with a structure like this:

```
file = {"date": current_date, "some parameters": parameters, "data": data}
numpy.save("file.npy", file)
```

The data field holds a large array (with dictionaries in each element!) that contributes the most in the file size, and I'd like to load the file in mmap mode therefore, otherwise the file opening process (np.load().item()) is too long even if I just want to access the "date" field.

However, loading the file in mmap_mode='r' does not work, since there is a dictionary is in the file.

```
np.load("test.npy", mmap_mode='r')
```

raises a ValueError exception:

```
ValueError: Array can't be memory-mapped: Python objects in dtype.
```

What else can I do to speed up the file opening time? I can't rewrite them now, so don't suggest alternative solutions such as PyTables and other databases. I do realize that the solution to data storage problem here is stupid.

Comment: `np.save` uses `pickle` to serialize and save non-array objects.  In this case you have an outer dictionary that has to be pickled.  `data` is an array, but its elements themselves are pickled dictionaries.  As the error says, `mmap_mode` can't handle that.  With a nice numeric array, `np.load` can easily determine where a given element, or slice, is located, almost as easily as if it were an array in memory.  But object dtypes use pointers to objects elsewhere in memory, or on the file, so it is nearly impossible to read your file piecemeal.

Comment: _What else can I do to speed up the file opening time?_ That depends, are you asking how to speed up the reading for a one-time thing, or for regular use in the program?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, well, I'll be stuck with these files for a while.

Comment: Then would it be worth suffering through the poor load time once, just to read it and rewrite it to a better format?